# How to hard reset to previous commit in libgit2?

Tags: c++, git, libgit2

My program (which uses libgit2) makes a commit to local repo (no push, only commit), then does *something* and then, according to the result, tries to revert the last commit by resetting repo to HEAD~1 (one commit before HEAD). Simply hard reset.

**The problem**: the code below does reset HEAD to HEAD~1, but leaves all changes between these 2 commit as "staged", while I need to simply erase these changes. What am I doing wrong?

```cpp
bool RevertLastCommit(std::string &errorMessage) 
{
    int error;
    git_object *head_commit_obj = nullptr;
    error = git_revparse_single(&head_commit_obj, repo, "HEAD~1");

    if (error < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    git_commit *head_commit = (git_commit *)head_commit_obj;

    git_checkout_options opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT;
    opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_FORCE;
    
    int reset_result = git_reset(repo, const_cast<git_object *>(head_commit_obj), GIT_RESET_HARD, &opts);
    
    if (reset_result < 0) {
        printf("Reset failed!\n");
        return false;
    }

    printf("Done reverting\n");

    error = git_checkout_head(repo, &opts);
    if (error < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    printf("Hard checkout\n");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue when fast-forwarding `master` to `origin/master`. The old code is left as staged meaning no changes are actually applied despite `HEAD` being moved. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: The code is correct - I've tested it on `libgit v1.0.0` and it resets to the last commit without leaving any changes behind.

The reset reverts changes already and checkout head should do the same as well. If this doesn't happen, there's likely a problem with libgit or the repository. Try the same with a different repo, and see if the same still happens. If it is consistently a problem, a reproducible git repo to test on would be useful.